# i have a rails undefined method `configure' for Rhoconnect:Module error when running rake exec db:restart

Tags: ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

please help.

I get an error while running the rails app.

`$ bundle exec rake db:reset`

rake aborted!

> `NoMethodError: undefined method`configure' for Rhoconnect:Module`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
bundle exec rhoconnect start
```

If it is doesn't work apply this:

Open the `Gemfile` of your application and find the rhoconnect line, it should look something like:

```
gem 'rhoconnect', '3.3.6'
```

Change this to the latest release version, which you can find on [rubygems.org](http://rubygems.org/gems/rhoconnect), for example if it is 3.4.0:

```
gem 'rhoconnect', '3.4.0'
```

Run the following command from the root application directory:

```
$ bundle install
```

Now update your application's RhoConnect dependency manifest:

```
$ rhoconnect update
```

Then try to run:

```
bundle exec rhoconnect start
```

Hopefully it will work.

Comment: thanks but it says ......"bundler: command not found: Rhoconnect
Install missing gem executables with `bundle install` ...." when i run bundle install it runs successfully but i dont see any gem about Rhoconnect in the gemfile

Comment: i have rhoconnect-rb (1.0.3) in my gemfile but still it does not run the ...."bundle exec rhoconnect start..."

Comment: :-( it stil giv me errors whn i run bundle exec rhoconnect start i get this   ......"/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:304:in `block in replace_gem': rhoconnect is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile. (Gem::LoadError)
     ....."  my rails -v is 4.2.6    ruby -v 2.3.0 n using #postgreSql
gem 'pg','0.18.4'